# How to automatically populate column values into another sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have certain columns in sheet one of an excel file that looks like this.

[image]

The `player No` and the `Player` has been manually created while the `Sold to` column has been selected using data validation (list).

Right now the sheet two of the excel file looks like this.

[image]

Now the question is how do I automatically populate the values of `Player No` and `Player` into the respective team(s)?

Expected output is as follows :-

[image]

I am currently using Excel version 2013. Can you suggest whether I should use any formula or Macros to achieve this ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you used to vba?

Comment: No Sir. I have not laid my hands on Macros and VBA. But if the solution requires that, I would be willing to learn it.

Comment: No need `VBA`. It can be done with formulas only.

Comment: Post your data instead of 1st screenshot so that we can copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter data based on condition. There are many way to do that. One of approch is as following.

As per below screenshot use below formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$7)-ROW($A$1))/($C$2:$C$7=$F$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

You have to adjust the formula for other team. For `Sheet 2` just you need to refer `Sheet 1` in formula like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$1))/(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7=$F$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```